# Insert record for each row returned

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a SQL Server trigger that inserts a record into an email queue table when a progress code is updated on an order. A service then sends the email.

I want to be able to send to more than 1 email address, but I have to get the email addresses from a query so I don't know how many I'm dealing with. So far I have the following which sends to a single email address:

```sql
IF UPDATE(prgcode)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.EmailQueue (emlLogged,
                                emlTo,
                                emlFrom,
                                emlSubject,
                                emlBody,
                                emlReady_bool,
                                emlContentType)
    SELECT GETDATE(),
           ISNULL(c.locEMail, (SELECT scffromaddress FROM dbo.SchedulerConfig)),
           (SELECT scffromaddress FROM dbo.SchedulerConfig) AS emailfrom,
           'Update on your order reference',
           'Some text in the body here',
           'T',
           'text/plain'
    FROM inserted i
         INNER JOIN dbo.Location c ON i.locLevel1 = c.locLevel1
                                  AND i.locLevel2 = c.locLevel2
                                  AND i.locLevel3 = c.locLevel3
                                  AND i.locLevel4 = c.locLevel4
                                  AND i.rgnCode = c.rgnCode
    WHERE i.prgCode = 'INVOICED';
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END;
```

I get the email address from the `c.locEmail` in the `LOCATION` table. But now I want to do the same as above, but get multiple email addresses stored in `LOCATION_CONTACTS` table - instead of the `LOCATION` table - which is joined to `INSERTED` by the same columns.

Instead of inserting 1 email into `emailqueue` table that uses a single static email address on the location table, I want to send the email to multiple email address that are stored in a separate table (`location_contacts`).

Instead of `c.locEMail` it would be `c.locEMail1`, `c.locEMail2`, `c.locEMail3`, etc. except I don't know how many there are or what values they are. It needs to loop through the results of

```
SELECT email_address 
FROM LOCATION_CONTACTS c
INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON i.LOCLEVEL1 = c.LOCLEVEL2, ETC
```

Comment: A `CURSOR` is the *last* thing you want to implement in a trigger.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking here, if I am honest. The problem seems to be in what ever mailer client you are using no? That's what's sending the emails. If it *is* the data side of things, then I think we need more of an explanation. Perhaps some sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: An INSERT/SELECT statement can insert more than one record. If the join to LOCATION_CONTACTS matches more than one record, you'll insert them all into EmailQueue. No Cursor needed or wanted.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Ah, yes. Of course it does. Going to give that a go. Thank you!

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help, as would the table definitions